# Color picker - suggestions for Chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome

In Chrome developer tools, instead of writing the hex code for a color it would be nice to pick from a color wheel or something like that. Does such a plugin exist?

Comment: Answer: this feature is already built in. Just click the color box shown next to the Hex value and a color picker will pop up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply [search the Google Chrome Web store for "**Color Picker**"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/color%20picker).

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

Please track the implementation progress of a color picker for the Chrome DevTools at http://webkit.org/b/71262.

Comment: This is now live in the stable release of Chrome

Comment: @BrianGrinstead, Alex. Where is it? Can't seem to find it anywhere in CtrlShiftJ

Comment: @Pacerier: Click a swatch square next to any color-aware property value in the `Styles` tab (`Elements` panel)

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov, Nice. Is there an alternative way to do it if there's no swatch squares in the `Styles` tab?

Answer (score 4):

Brian Grindstead has a work-in-progress in his blog

[Chrome Developer Tools Colorpicker Concept](http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/chrome-developer-tools-colorpicker-concept)

edit:
Somehow late but noticed chrome now has this feature built-in (starting I think version 20+ ?)

Comment: correct---just click the colored box next to the hex value

Answer (score 0):

ColorZilla is a nice choice...
http://www.colorzilla.com/chrome/